# How do I terminate a loop?

Tags: 7, rules

I'm using a loop to loop through the items in a entity form list. I then use an if condition using the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module, within this loop.

I would like to break from the loop once this if condition is evaluated to true.

**More details**:

The exact situation is like this:

1. I have created a loop in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to look through a set of items of entity forms.
2. This loop has a "if condition" that uses a data comparison of a particular field.
3. Now if this "if condition" evaluates to true, the loop should not evaluate the rest of the items in the list on which the loop is to run.
4. Instead, it should break out of the loop.

Any suggestions?

Comment: pls provide more details on this

Comment: The exact situation is like this : 1. I have created a loop in rules to look through a set of items of entity forms. 2. This loop has a "if condition" that uses a data comparison of a particular field. 3. Now if this "if condition" evaluates to true, the loop should not evaluate the rest of the items in the list on which the loop is to run. 4. Instead, it should break out of the loop.

Comment: did you find any answer for this? I need exactly the same.